# How to retrieve DynamicData DetailsView Viewstate when a SqlException occurs during Inserting?

Tags: linq-to-sql, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

Using DyanamicData, I have a standard Many-to-Many table that is working perfectly fine when inserting a new unique row.  The dropdownlists for both Parent tables display as they should, and the row gets inserted correctly.

However, on one table, I have a Unique Index, which throws an exception that I can catch in the OnInserted event handler.  I can then post back a nice friendly message to the user, informing them of the problem.  The problem occurs because the DetailsView loses the viewstate and the values that the user had selected for the DropDownLists gets reset back to the page's defaults.

```
protected void DetailsDataSource_Inserted(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null && !e.ExceptionHandled)
    {
        msgPanel.Text = "Error Occurred"; // or some other friendly message
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;

        // e.Result == null, so I can't rebuild the user's input from here.
        // What can be put where to get the user's input restored?
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the question not clear, or does no one have a solution for this?  I can't be the only person who is having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to wrap the error in a Validation exception in the model this results in a Validation Error and should leave your user input intact.

Steve